# Not finding the class "box-category treemenu" in stylesheet.css

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

I am creating an e-commerce website for the first time. I decreased the overall width of the website body and but this caused the product list and description to move down. I am not able to figure out the CSS property which is to be edited in order to make the product list and information appear on the right of the category treemenu. 
This is the product description page I would like to fix http://kingadlerhomedecor.com/store/index.php?route=product/category&path=75_82

**Category TPL file**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="cbox-heading"><span><?php echo $heading_title; ?></span></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <ul class="box-category treemenu">
      <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
      <li>
        <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><span><?php echo $category['name']; ?></span></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $category['name']; ?></span></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
          <li>
            <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"><span><?php echo $child['name']; ?></span></a>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $child['name']; ?></span></a>
            <?php } ?>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Products TPL file:**

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<?php echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?>
<div id="content"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
  <div class="box">
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="product-info">
    <?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
    <div class="right" style="width: <?php echo $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width') + 20 ?>px;">
      <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
      <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /></a></div>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="image"><span class="no-image"><img src="image/no_image.jpg" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /></span></div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($images) { ?>
      <div class="image-additional clearafter">
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="left" style="margin-right: <?php echo $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width') + 75 ?>px;">
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <?php if ($price) { ?>
      <div class="price">
        <?php if (!$special) { ?>
        <div><span class="price-fixed"><?php echo $price; ?></span></div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="special-price"><span class="price-fixed"><?php echo $special; ?></span><span class="price-old"><?php echo $price; ?></span></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($tax) { ?>
        <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $tax; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($points) { ?>
        <span class="reward"><?php echo $text_points; ?> <?php echo $points; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($discounts) { ?>
        <p class="discount">
          <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
          <?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?><br />
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
      <div class="review">
        <img src="catalog/view/theme/acceptus/image/icons/stars-<?php echo $rating; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $reviews; ?>" /><a class="show-review" href="#tabs"><?php echo $reviews; ?></a>
        <a class="new-review" href="#tabs"><?php echo $text_write; ?></a>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="description">
        <?php if ($manufacturer) { ?>
        <span><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></span> <a href="<?php echo $manufacturers; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer; ?></a><br />
        <?php } ?>
        <span><?php echo $text_model; ?></span> <?php echo $model; ?><br />
        <?php if ($reward) { ?>
        <span><?php echo $text_reward; ?></span> <?php echo $reward; ?><br />
        <?php } ?>
        <span><?php echo $text_stock; ?></span> <?php echo $stock; ?><br />
        <span><?php echo $text_qty; ?></span> <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" /> <?php if ($minimum > 1) { ?>
        <div class="minimum"><?php echo $text_minimum; ?></div>
        <?php } ?></div>
      <?php if ($profiles): ?>
      <div class="option">
          <h2><span class="required">*</span><?php echo $text_payment_profile ?></h2>
          <br />
          <select name="profile_id">
              <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
              <?php foreach ($profiles as $profile): ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $profile['profile_id'] ?>"><?php echo $profile['name'] ?></option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
          <br />
          <br />
          <span id="profile-description"></span>
          <br />
          <br />
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($options) { ?>
      <h2><?php echo $text_option; ?></h2>
      <div class="options">
        <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
            <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option multi">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <div>
          <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
          <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
          </label>
          <br />
          <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option multi">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <div>
          <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
          <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
          <label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
          </label>
          <br />
          <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'image') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <table class="option-image">
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 1px;"><input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" /></td>
              <td><label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" /></label></td>
              <td><label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                  <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                  (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                  <?php } ?>
                </label></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'text') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'textarea') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option multi">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <textarea name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" cols="40" rows="5"><?php echo $option['option_value']; ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_upload; ?>" id="button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="" />
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'date') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="date" />
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'datetime') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="datetime" />
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'time') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" class="time" />
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="cart">
        <div>
          <button class="button highlight" id="button-cart"><span><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="icon-wishlist-grey" onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a>
          <a class="icon-compare-grey" onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a>
          <div class="share clearafter"><!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
          <div class="addthis_default_style"><a class="addthis_button_compact"><?php echo $text_share; ?></a> <a class="addthis_button_email"></a><a class="addthis_button_print"></a> <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a> <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a></div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script> 
          <!-- AddThis Button END --> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs" class="htabs clearafter"><a href="#tab-description"><?php echo $tab_description; ?></a>
    <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-attribute"><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-review"><?php echo $tab_review; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-description" class="tab-content"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
  <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
  <div id="tab-attribute" class="tab-content">
    <table class="attribute">
      <?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
  <div id="tab-review" class="tab-content">
    <div id="review"></div>
    <h2 id="review-title"><?php echo $text_write; ?></h2>
    <p class="clearafter">
    <strong><?php echo $entry_name; ?></strong>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    </p>
    <p class="clearafter">
    <strong><?php echo $entry_review; ?></strong>
    <textarea name="text" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p><?php echo $text_note; ?></p>
    <p>
    <strong><?php echo $entry_rating; ?></strong> <span><?php echo $entry_bad; ?></span>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" />
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
    <span><?php echo $entry_good; ?></span>
    </p>
    <div class="captcha-field clearafter">
      <div class="left"><strong><?php echo $entry_captcha; ?></strong></div>
      <div class="right">
        <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" />
        <p><img src="index.php?route=product/product/captcha" alt="" id="captcha" /></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="right"><a id="button-review" class="button"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($products) { ?>
  <div class="box-heading"><span><?php echo $tab_related; ?></span></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box-product product-grid">
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <?php
        $thumb_width = $this->config->get('config_image_related_width');
        $thumb_height = $this->config->get('config_image_related_height');
      ?>
      <div>
        <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" style="<?php echo ($thumb_height < 208) ? 'line-height: 208px' : ''; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="image">
            <span class="no-image" style="<?php echo ($thumb_width < 208) ? 'width: 208px' : 'width: '.$thumb_width.'px'; ?>; <?php echo ($thumb_height < 208) ? 'line-height: 208px' : 'line-height: '.$thumb_height.'px;'; ?>">
            <img src="image/no_image.jpg" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></span>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <div class="price-label">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <div><span class="price-fixed"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span></div>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <div class="special-price"><span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span><span class="price-fixed"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/acceptus/image/icons/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="name" style="width: <?php echo $thumb_width; ?>px"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <div class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <div><span class="price-fixed"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span></div>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <div class="special-price"><span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span><span class="price-fixed"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="details">
        <div class="cart"><a onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><span><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></a></div>
        <div class="wishlist"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><span><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></span></a></div>
        <div class="compare"><a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><span><?php echo $button_compare; ?></span></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($tags) { ?>
  <div class="tags"><strong><?php echo $text_tags; ?></strong>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++) { ?>
    <?php if ($i < (count($tags) - 1)) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>,
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({
        overlayClose: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        rel: "colorbox"
    });
});
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

$('select[name="profile_id"], input[name="quantity"]').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/getRecurringDescription',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('input[name="product_id"], input[name="quantity"], select[name="profile_id"]'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#profile-description').html('');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#profile-description').html(json['success']);
            }   
        }
    });
});

$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }

                if (json['error']['profile']) {
                    $('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>');
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
<?php if ($options) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ajaxupload.js"></script>
<?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
new AjaxUpload('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>', {
    action: 'index.php?route=product/product/upload',
    name: 'file',
    autoSubmit: true,
    responseType: 'json',
    onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').after('<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" class="loading" style="padding-left: 5px;" />');
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').attr('disabled', true);
    },
    onComplete: function(file, json) {
        $('#button-option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').attr('disabled', false);

        $('.error').remove();

        if (json['success']) {
            alert(json['success']);

            $('input[name=\'option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]\']').attr('value', json['file']);
        }

        if (json['error']) {
            $('#option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>').after('<span class="error">' + json['error'] + '</span>');
        }

        $('.loading').remove(); 
    }
});
//--></script>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#review .pagination a').live('click', function() {
    $('#review').fadeOut('slow');

    $('#review').load(this.href);

    $('#review').fadeIn('slow');

    return false;
});         

$('#review').load('index.php?route=product/product/review&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>');

$('#button-review').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/write&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'name=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'name\']').val()) + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent($('textarea[name=\'text\']').val()) + '&rating=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').val() ? $('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').val() : '') + '&captcha=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'captcha\']').val()),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.success, .warning').remove();
            $('#button-review').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#review-title').after('<div class="attention"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /> <?php echo $text_wait; ?></div>');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-review').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.attention').remove();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['error']) {
                $('#review-title').after('<div class="warning">' + data['error'] + '</div>');
            }

            if (data['success']) {
                $('#review-title').after('<div class="success">' + data['success'] + '</div>');

                $('input[name=\'name\']').val('');
                $('textarea[name=\'text\']').val('');
                $('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').attr('checked', '');
                $('input[name=\'captcha\']').val('');
            }
        }
    });
});
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#tabs a').tabs();
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6) {
        $('.date, .datetime, .time').bgIframe();
    }

    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    $('.datetime').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'h:m'
    });
    $('.time').timepicker({timeFormat: 'h:m'});
});
//--></script> 
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your given link. In line no 220 change the style to bellow:

```
.primary-define #column-left + #content, .primary-define #column-right + #content {
float: right; /* You can use the float left property also. But right is best choice */ 
/* width: 820px; Remove this width property */ 
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you sandeep. This worked like a charm. Thanks for your response, it would have taken me eternity to fix that.  But as you can see <http://kingadlerhomedecor.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50> The there is a lot of space between the category tree and the product information, is there anything I can do to correct that by changing the width of the category treemenu.

Comment: What happen?? category tree?? On left side menu??

Comment: 1 - <div class="left" style="margin-right: 425px;"> Remove the margin right property.

2 - <div class="right" style="width: 370px;"> Make the width 176px.

Comment: yes, there is white space between the categories on the left and the product description on the right. Can I fix it somehow? I have added the code to category TPL above. Please help.

Comment: 1 - <div class="left" style="margin-right: 425px;"> Remove the margin right property. 2 - <div class="right" style="width: 370px;"> Make the width 176px.

Comment: See my upper comment. I gave two points to make changes.
You told about the space between categories and product description.
This is not space, the theme is design this way Left panel and right panel. So your left panel content line is small, so its showing space. No worry about it.

Comment: This is increasing and decreasing the size of the product image. I would want to decrease the white space between my product title "DESK Football Clubs" and the "Categories" on the left of the page. As you can see there is a lot of white space between two. Can you help me decrease the width of the "vertical category list" here?

Comment: That means, it is part of the theme design and I should not worry about it?

Comment: Thanks bro. Appreciate your help. :) :)

Comment: Happy to help :) This is my tag line.

Comment: Hi Sandy, I need a small help again, [http://kingadlerhomedecor.com/store/index.php?route=common/home] in the above page, when we hover over the featured product, the size of the element covers the heading "Latest", I have tried to fix that, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you suggest how it can be done? I would also, like to decrease the size of the area occupied by a single product. Can it be done? Please help me through. Thanks

Comment: What you want to do? Can you give me a screenshot of your desired layout.

Comment: Here in the first image - <http://postimg.org/image/vfbgsyt0h/> you can see that the "Latest" module can be seen, but when we hover over the product, the heading "Latest" gets overlapped - see it in this screenshot <http://postimg.org/image/atj4zioar/> I want to make sure that there is no overlapping of "Latest" module when I hover over the product. Can it be done?

Comment: I can't elaborate it more friend. Its taking time and its just a simple css changes. So make yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing below css on line 220,

http://kingadlerhomedecor.com/store/catalog/view/theme/acceptus/stylesheet/stylesheet.css

```
.primary-define #column-left + #content, .primary-define #column-right + #content {
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :). Thanks for your response, it would have taken me eternity to fix that. But as you can see [http://kingadlerhomedecor.com/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50] There is a lot of space between category tree and the product description - can I fix it somehow?